# $\mathcal{B} = \{\{a\} \times (b,c) \subset \mathbb{R}^2|a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}\}$ is a basis for some topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Tags: general-topology

Say we have $\mathcal{B} = \{\{a\} \times (b,c) \subset \mathbb{R}^2|a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}\}$.

*I'm trying to show that $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis for some topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$.*

In this case, $\mathcal{B}$ is the set of open vertical line segments from $(a,b)$ to $(a,c)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

A basis for a topology on $X$ is a collection $B$ of subsets of $X$ satisfying two criteria:

1. For each $x \in X$, there is at least one basis element $B$ containing $x$.
2. If $x$ belongs to the intersection of two basis elements $B_1$ and $B_2$, then there is a basis element $B_3$ containing $x$ such that $B_3 \subset B_1 \cap B_2$.

I'm having a bit of trouble wrapping my head around this. $\mathcal{B}$ is a set of open vertical lines and there does not appear to be restrictions on the location of $a$, so it seems like any $x \in \mathbb{R}$ could potentially be covered by some vertical line in $\mathcal{B}$.
Say we have any point $(x,y)$. If it is not contained in a vertical line between two points $b$ and $c$, then we can choose two other points, using the fact that $b$ and $c$ are arbitrary. This seems a bit too simple to satisfy criterion 1, so I feel like I'm missing something.

For criterion 2, it seems like a matter of dividing vertical line segments into subsegments by manipulating/choosing $b$ and $c$ as with criterion 1.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it could be healthy to explicitly write down how the set $\mathcal{B}$ satisfies both properties:

1. Let $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$. We need to a find a set $ B \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $x \in B$. Pick any the set $\{x\} \times (y-1,y+1) $ contains $(x,y)$, also $\{x\}\times (y-1,y+1) \in \mathcal{B}$. Notice that $(x,y)$ is arbitrary.
2. Let $(x,y) \in B_1 \cap B_2 $ where $B_1,B_2 \in \mathcal{B}$. Since $(x,y) \in B_1$, and $(x,y) \in B_2$, then $B_1$ and $B_2$ must be of the form $B_1 = \{x\}\times (a,b)$ and $B_2 = \{x\} \times (c,d)$ where
   $$
   a < y < b \quad \text{and} \quad c < y < d
    $$
   Can you find $B_3 \subset B_1 \cap B_2$ such that $B_3 \in \mathcal{B}$ ?